# Android retain fragments on ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, retain

in my activity i have `ViewPager` which that implemented for two `fragments`, in these fragments i have some popup such as dialog which on rotate device popups start again, this popups is on `createview` and after running parent activity i get some data from server, how can i retain these fragments not to load again on change device orientation ?

Activity:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    adapter = new RegisterViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    //adapter.addFragment(new FragmentEmpty());
    adapter.addFragment(FragmentCheckValidationCode.getInstance());
    adapter.addFragment(FragmentRegisterPhoneNumber.getInstance());

    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    registerPages.setCurrentItem(1);
    registerPages.setPageMargin(50);
    registerPages.setScrollDurationFactor(5);
}
```

fragments:

```
public static FragmentCheckValidationCode getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new FragmentCheckValidationCode();
    }
    return instance;
}
```

FragmentCheckValidationCode:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //@formatter:off
        activity                  = getActivity();
        context                   = getActivity().getBaseContext();
    //@formatter:on

    setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

Comment: Use FragmentPagerAdapter instead of FragmentStatePagerAdapter. This will load all fragments into memory. For retaining the instance see @SaravInferns answer

Comment: @NinoHandler i change `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and add `setRetainInstance(true);` into `onCreate`, fragment with dialogs load again

Comment: do you use a different layout for landscape? if not you could add
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" to your Activity in you Manifest

Comment: @NinoHandler problem solved, thanks please send this comment as reply and let me to accept that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't use a different layout for the landscape mode you could add the tag

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
```

to your Activity in your Manifest. This tells the system that you handle the configuration change by yourself.

Comment: thanks and what about different layout? how can i manage that?

Comment: then you have to find a different solution:
- create a DialogFragment and show it with a tag
- check in onViewCreated() getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(DIALOG_TAG) and show it again...

Comment: if my question helps, please also vote for it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

in your fragment's onCreate use setRetainIntanse(true);

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Retain this fragment across configuration changes.
    setRetainInstance(true);

  }
```

refer [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance(boolean))

Comment: i have that on `onCreate` but fragment couldn't retain